# Dynamically realloc 2 dim array in callback function of sqlite

Tags: c, arrays, sqlite, multidimensional-array, realloc

I am working on a sqlite-.dll for educational purpose.
I am trying to dynamically add a row in my 2 dimensional array for each time the callback function is called with a new row from the database. (e.g. SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER).
The data stored in this array should then be returned as a C-Interface.

```
SQLCONTROL_API char** sql_execQuery(char *dbName, char *sqlStatement)
{
    char **a = 0;
    /*Some sqlite stuff*/
    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement, callback, &a, &zErrMsg);
    return a;
}
```

With the callback function:

```
static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    char **old = (char **)data;
    int num_rows = sizeof(old) / sizeof(old[0]);
    int num_cols = sizeof(old[0]) / sizeof(old[0][0]);

    old = (char **)realloc(old, (num_rows + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < (num_rows + 1); i++)
        old[i] = (char *)realloc(old[i], argc * sizeof(char *));

    /*I am trying to create a 2 dim array that looks like a table, 
    so the column names are in the first row, 
    then the data from the table is stored in each row*/
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (num_rows == 1)
            old[0][i] = *azColName[i];

        old[num_rows][i] = *argv[i];
    }
    data = old;
    return 0;
}
```

When inserting data to the database, everything works fine. But when I try to retrieve data, I get read access violation.
Now my question, am I on the right way with my approach or do I miss some important requirements for my intention?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `sqlite3_exec()` instead of the cursor interface?

Comment: @CL. Since the `sqlite3_exec()` is a wrapper function I thought I would achieve better and faster coding results than implementing each step.

Answer (score 0):

In your `sql_execQuery()`, you declare `a` as a `char **`, and you pass its *address*, `&a`, as the fourth argument of `sqlite3_exec()`.  That argument therefore has type `char ***`, and it points to a location somewhere in the program's stack.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that.

But then we get to `callback()`, which has serious problems, principal among them:

- It treats the `data` pointer as if it were of type `char **`, instead of the correct type, `char ***`.  If that were your only problem, you could fix it like this:

```
char **old = *(char ***)data;

// ...

*(char ***)data = old;
```

- It tries to compute the dimensions of the allocated space via the `sizeof` operator, as would be reasonable if `old` were, in fact, a 2D array, but ***it is not an array at all***.  It is a pointer to pointer to `char`, so `sizeof(old)` is the size of a pointer (to pointer to `char`), `sizeof(old[0])` is the size of a pointer (to `char`) and `sizeof(old[0][0])` is the size of a `char`.  This does not tell you anything about how much space has been allocated.
- After allocating memory for `old`, it dereferences the parts of the allocated memory without initializing them, by passing them to `realloc()`.  Generally, all but one of these will have been initialized, but the one uninitialized one causes `realloc()` to exhibit undefined behavior.
- You fail to check for allocation errors.

It looks like you need a more complex data structure to be passed through to your callback, so that you can track the allocated dimensions.  Something like this, for example:

```
struct mytable {
    char **data;
    size_t dim;
};

SQLCONTROL_API char** sql_execQuery(char *dbName, char *sqlStatement)
{
    struct mytable a = { NULL, 0 };

    // ...

    int rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement, callback, &a, &zErrMsg);

    return a.data;
}

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    struct mytable *old = data;
    char **temp;

    old->dim++;
    temp = realloc(old->data, old->dim * sizeof(*old->data));
    if (temp) {
        old->data = temp;
        old->data[old->dim - 1] = NULL;
    } else {
        // handle allocation error ...
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < old->dim; i++) {
        char *temp2 = realloc(old->data[i], argc * sizeof(*old->data[i]));

        if (temp2) {
            old->data[i] = temp2;
            old->data[i][argc - 1] = NULL;
        } else {
            // handle allocation error ...
        }
    }

    // ... other stuff ...

    // no need for anything like data = old

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your help i achieved that I get the first character of each column. I´ve tried to get the full `char*` string from the `char** argv` array. Do I need a 3d array, so something like `char ***temp` ?

Comment: @Strizzi, that sounds like a separate question, based on your revised code.

Comment: I´ve created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117774/creating-an-2d-array-of-char-an-fill-it-with-data-from-sqlite-in-callback-funct).