# Creating an 2D Array of char* an fill it with data from sqlite in callback function

Tags: c, arrays, sqlite, malloc

In my function I call the `rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlStatement, callback, &a, &zErrMsg);` function with the `callback` function.
In this `callback` function I want to fill a 2D Array of char* with the data from the database.

```
struct mytable 
{
    char ***data;
    size_t dim;
};

static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    struct mytable *old = (mytable *)data;
    char ***temp;

    old->dim++;
    temp = (char ***)realloc(old->data, old->dim * sizeof(*old->data));
    if (temp) 
    {
        old->data = temp;
        old->data[old->dim - 1] = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        logging_logError("Kein virtueller RAM mehr vorhanden ... !", __FILE__);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < old->dim; i++) 
    {
        char **temp2 = (char **)realloc(old->data[i], sizeof(argv) * sizeof(*old->data[i]));

        if (temp2) 
        {
            old->data[i] = temp2;
            old->data[i][argc - 1] = NULL;
        }
        else 
        {
            logging_logError("Kein virtueller RAM mehr vorhanden ... !", __FILE__);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    /*Here I try to store the data from each column 
     in the corresponding position in the 2D array of char* */
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        char *s = argv[i];
        temp[old->dim - 1][i] = s;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I print out the data I returned, I get some mysterious signs.
What I want to have is something like this (in array structure):

```
["1"]["Paul"]["street 1"]["some address"]
["2"]["Anna"]["street asdf"]["some address"]
["3"]["Martin"]["street bfg"]["some address"]
```

**EDIT:**
This was my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096266/dynamically-realloc-2-dim-array-in-callback-function-of-sqlite)

Comment: For starters you shouldn't cast the `realloc` (probably not the cause of your issues, but you still shouldn't do it)

Comment: @UnholySheep. When I remove the cast the compiler states that he can´t convert from void* to char***. Btw I am using VS 2015.

Comment: The cast is optional and not recommended in C, but required in C++.  Historically, VS has been quirky and non-conforming as a C compiler, though I have heard that VS 2015 is better in that regard than older versions.  Use the cast if you must, but if there's some project option you can set to tell VS to act as a conforming C compiler then that would be far preferable.  Note that there are more dangerous differences between C and C++ than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't find it documented specifically, but it seems probable that the `argv` strings passed into your callback are good only until the callback returns.  I don't see how SQLite could work otherwise -- the callback is not responsible for managing the memory for those strings, so SQLite must do so internally.

Therefore, instead of recording the original string pointers in your array, duplicate the strings, and store pointers to the duplicates.  MSVC++ provides `strdup()`, so you might achieve that by replacing ...

```
        char *s = argv[i];
```

... with ...

```
        char *s = strdup(argv[i]);
```

.  Do be aware that by doing so you assume responsibility for freeing those strings when you're done with them.

Comment: Thank you so much John. This was the problem. Now I get the full data returned.